# Rails 5 belongs_to_required_by_default doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.0.0, but for some reason `belongs_to_required_by_default` doesn't work!

Application was created as new rails 5 app

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

> v = Visit.new
> v.valid? # => true
```

it works only with `optional: false` option

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: false
end

> v = Visit.new
> v.valid? # => false
```

but why doesn't work configuration:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Where are you putting it? Have confirmed it works by putting it in `development.rb` as `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true` inside `Rails.application.configure do`.

If you want it for everything you can put it in `application.rb` under class `Application < Rails::Application` as `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true`

I believe you'll find putting it in the initializers directory will have problems with the loading order.

Comment: I have it by default in `my_app/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`

Comment: if you want it for everything you can put it in `application.rb` under `class Application < Rails::Application` as `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true`

Comment: yep it works as for your answer, but I can't understand, why it doesn't initialize from initializers folder?

Comment: I believe its due to initialization order.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT FOR RAILS 5.1:** Everything should work well on a default Rails 5.1 application. Just make sure `config.load_defaults 5.1` is in your application.rb ([reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589#issuecomment-305557647)).

**OLD ANSWER FOR RAILS 5.0.x**

It look like this is due to some gems that monkey patch activerecord incorrectly, according to this Rails issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589.

You may want to comment/uncomment them out in your Gemfile until you find the culprit.

After this tedious process, I found that for my latest project it was the gems `ahoy_matey`, `cancancan` and `delayed_job_active_record` that caused the problem (at the time of writing).

In the meantime Ropeney's answer works, although not ideal since the "official rails way" is to declare `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true` in the `new_framework_default‌​s.rb` initializer, not in `application.rb`.

Comment: delayed_job_active_record is still not fixed, so the workaround in `application.rb` is still needed even for Rails 5.2

Comment: For those still on Rails 5.0, adding `::ActiveRecord = 1` to config/application.rb before the `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` line may help weed out the offending gem(s), per p8 on GitHub: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589#issuecomment-509303497

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone is still having this issue, you can upgrade to Rails 5.1 to fix it. In Rails 5.1, `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`has been removed and replaced with the line `config.load_defaults 5.1` in `application.rb`. This line includes 
 `active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true` and the other options that were in `new_framework_defaults.rb`.

```
module myApp
 class Application < Rails::Application
 # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails 
 version.
  config.load_defaults 5.1
```

See the end of this thread for more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589.

Answer (score -1):

active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true only works for FactoryBot.create() method. you will still get validation error of child records not present where you have used FactoryBot.build() method. Any idea why this is not working for build()? any workaround?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).